# XAMPP manager-osx MySQL Database is OFF - but the status in MySQL Workbench is ON

Tags: mysql, sql-server, macos, xampp, mysql-workbench

When I start manager-osx on Mac (Mojave - 10.14.6), MySQL Database server won't start (it stays stuck on *Running...* and then switches to *Stopped*), but by checking the status of the server on MySQL Workbench, it is indeed running.

So I don't know if the server is operational or not?

Here is a screenshot of the situation:

[image]

I tried to make MySQL Database work by changing the port number but also by trying to start it from the terminal using the following command:

`sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start`

Here's what I get:

`Starting MySQL | SUCCESS!`

But on manager-osx, MySQL Database is still blocked on *Stopped*.

Comment: Tag properly. MySQL is NOT SQL Server.

Comment: Oh sorry Jean-Claude